# How to avoid visible refresh in sdl2

Tags: c, sdl-2

In a situation like this one:

```c
void Game_run(struct Game *game)
{
    //Previous rendering are cleared.
    SDL_RenderClear(game->renderer);
    //We are payng
    game->state = PLAYING;
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_bool GameRunning = SDL_TRUE;

    render_basic_elements(game);

    while (GameRunning) //while the player didnt loose, the game is running
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            //when a key is pressed
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                                //Detecting the pressed key
                                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                                {
                                case SDLK_LEFT:

                                    printf("Left key pressed\n");
                                    Move_Cursor_Left(game);
                                    break;
                                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                                    printf("Right key pressed\n");
                                    Move_Cursor_Right(game);
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                                }
                break;
            //when a key is unpressed
            case SDL_KEYUP:
                                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                                {
                                case SDLK_LEFT:
                                    printf("Left key up\n");
                                    break;
                                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                                    printf("Right key up\n");
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                                }
                break;
            //if the user quit the game
            case SDL_QUIT:
                //The game is over
                GameRunning = SDL_FALSE;
                game->state = GAME_OVER;
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
void render_Arc(struct Game *game){
        //refresh
        SDL_RenderClear(game->renderer);
        //i render the background again
        Spritesheet_render(game->background, BACKGROUND_X, BACKGROUND_Y, 255, 0);
        // i am drawing an arc
        arcRGBA(game->renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 100, 0, 80, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        //i render my stuff
        SDL_RenderPresent(game->renderer);
};
```

How can i render stuff (refresh the screen with new elements or just static elements using sdl_gfx) without seeing it appear and disappear very fast?

I normally use

`SDL_RenderClear(game->renderer);`

Draw my stuff and then

`SDL_RenderPresent(game->renderer);`

But i dont like the refreshing effect.
Am I doing something wrong or thats something normal?

**Update**:
where should i put `render_Arc(struct Game *game)` to always be rendered without seeing it come and go fast when there is an event for example?

Comment: Render to an offscreen buffer and only draw what's different.

Comment: Im very new to this kind of programmation and im not sure what is a offscreen buffer.

Comment: @Hazel Normally you shouldn't see the effects you're talking about. Can you make a [mcve] that demonstrates them?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I added more context and a specific question.

Comment: *"where should i put render_Arc(struct Game *game)"* In your main loop (`while (GameRunning)`), outside of the event loop.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i still see it appear and disappear super fast. its not a big issue but im wondering if there is a way to avoid that lol

Comment: Do you see any flickering if you don't use SDL_gfx?

Comment: I dont know i never tried, my teacher told us to use that to draw stuff in our screen and also, i dont know how i can draw without gfx (using spritesheets is too much for just an arc).

Comment: Its fine once I animate it, i dont see visible flickering.